# Android RelativeLayout over SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-relativelayout, surfaceview

I have a very atypical problem, I overlayed an AnimationView(RelativeLayout) on CameraView(SurfaceView) using a container(RelativeLayout) for this, but the AnimationView shown cut adding after the CameraView

Here is my Activity onCreate code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

    cameraView = new CameraView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams surfaceLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    cameraView.setLayoutParams(surfaceLayoutParams);
    container.addView(cameraView);

    animationView = new AnimationView(this);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
     animationView.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

    container.addView(animationView);

    animationView.startAnimation();
}
```

And show cutting the AnimationView: http://s13.postimage.org/d62piuko7/Untitled.png

But when dont add the CameraView the animation shows great: http://s18.postimage.org/sycfdq2mx/Untitled2.png